# scroll to closest href tab jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to click a link and scroll to a tab that exists on my page. The issue is the id I am scrolling to exists twice on the page. When I click the scroll trigger it is scrolling to the id after the one I want to scroll to. is there a way to use closest() or find the next tab with the specific ID?

```
jquery:

   $('.link-to-management').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkTo = $(this).attr('href');

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:
            $(linkTo).offset().top - 55
        },350);
    });


html: 

 <a href="#to-management-tab" class="link-to-management">
 Assess response, adjust, and review</a>

div scrolling to:

<div class="tab-scroller__nav" id="to-management-tab"></div>
```

Comment: "The issue is the id I am scrolling to exists twice on the page." -- that's your biggest problem right there. IDs are meant to be *unique*. If you ever have more than one DOM element on the page with the same ID at the same time, you're doing something wrong. Whatever reason you have for using the same ID twice will probably point you in the direction of a better approach.

Comment: unfortunately I am using AEM cms so it injects the id twice, one for mobile and one for desktop

Comment: I don't know anything about AEM, but if it's using the same ID twice, something is very wrong. At the very least, the ID should be prefixed or suffixed to specify which is for mobile and which is for desktop; at best, only one would be rendered on the screen at a time depending on the platform. AEM is from Adobe; I can't imagine they'd do something like that. Are you sure there's no setting or option or some way in AEM to prevent that duplicate ID?

Comment: I don't know much about it either, trying to learn as much as possible. Had this project kinda thrown at me. I'm wondering If I can go about it another way, maybe not use href / id to scroll. I appreciate your help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know by the comments, multiple elements with the same ID is bad. Really bad. But I do understand that part of it is not under your control.

So in that case, what I would do is tweaking the code a bit to work without ID's:

### jQuery

```
$('.link-to-management').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkTo = $(this).attr('href');

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:
        $('[data-id=" + linkTo + "]').first().offset().top - 55
    },350);
});
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#to-management-tab" class="link-to-management">
Assess response, adjust, and review</a>

...

<div class="tab-scroller__nav" data-id="#to-management-tab"></div>
```

### What Did I Do?

Not much, if you really need to know. Just changed the `id` into `data-id` so you don't get punished for using same ID twice, updating the jQuery selector so it can handle the new `data-id` attribute, and adding `first()` so it chooses the first element as you mentioned.